# playsinline Limitation on iOS Chrome: Achieving True Video Invisibility for Audio Playback

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

Why is the playsinline attribute not working for inline video playback in the latest versions of Chrome on iOS devices?

Despite implementing various solutions from Stack Overflow, I'm unable to achieve a completely hidden video with audio playback using playsinline on the latest Chrome for iOS. I'm expecting that video should not visible on the screen. Are there reliable methods for hiding the video completely while still allowing audio playback in this scenario?